# needing some development guidance as im super new to react super excited to see

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The Code below displays the input fields with the onChange functions `handleNameChange` and `handleNameChange` and the submit button with onClick function `submit`

```
import React from 'react'

class Adder extends React.Component {

    state = {
        name:"",
        points: 0
    }

    handleNameChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            name: event.target.value
        })

    }

    handlePointsChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            points: parseInt(event.target.value)
        })
    }


    render(){
        const submit = () => {
            if(this.props.hasOwnProperty("onSubmit")){
                this.props.onSubmit(this.state.name, this.state.points);
            }
        }

        return(
            <div>
                <input 
                type="text"
                onChange={this.handleNameChange}
                />
                <input
                type="number" 
                onChange={this.handlePointsChange}
                />
                <button onClick={submit}>Submit</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
} 

export default Adder
```

The adder updates contestant data and lifts to the below leaderboarddisplay

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Adder from "./Adder";

export default class LeaderboardDisplay extends Component {

    state = {
        contestantData: {}
      }


      updateContestantData = (name, points) => {
        if(this.state.contestantData.hasOwnProperty(name)){
          this.setState({
            contestantData: {
            ...this.state.contestantData,
            [name]:this.state.contestantData[name] + points
            }
          })
        } else {
          this.setState({
            contestantData: {
              ...this.state.contestantData,
              [name]: points
            }
          })
        }

      }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    <h2>hhhhhhhh</h2>
                </div>
                <Adder onSubmit={this.updateContestantData}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

finally in app i want to display the contestant data thats been input in the fields and display it here

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import LeaderboardDisplay from './LeaderboardDisplay';
import contestantData from "./LeaderboardDisplay";

class App extends React.Component {
    render () {
    return(
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
              <LeaderboardDisplay/>
        </header>
      </div>
    )
  }
 }

export default App;
```

Comment: Are you facing any issues?

Comment: Hi Ramesh no but i would like to ask how would you display the data as the functions are all working and would just like to know how we can display the data once its been recorded

Comment: in app i want to display the contestant data thats been input in the fields and display it here

Comment: Do you want to display the data in the place of `<div>
                    <h2>hhhhhhhh</h2>
                </div>` inside `LeaderboardDisplay` component?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `LeaderboardDisplay` component's `render` method you can use:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {Object.entries(this.state.contestantData).map(([name, points]) => (
        <div key={`${name}+${points}`}>
          <span>{name}</span>
          <span>{points}</span>
        </div>
      ))}
      <Adder onSubmit={this.updateContestantData} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

You can improve the `updateContestantData` function so that when the state should update it only updates after the previous updations are done. It can also be written in fewer lines.

```
updateContestantData = (name, points) => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    contestantData: {
      ...prevState.contestantData,
      [name]: (prevState.contestantData[name] || 0) + points
    }
  }))
}
```

Comment: how would i compare the data of the different contestants

Comment: @kodamace Can you be more specific, what are you trying to do?